# React Native Flatlist not rendering but show ActivityIndicator

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My React Native Flatlist is not rendering. It does not show any error nor does the app crash. It just shows an ActivityIndicator

home.js

```
export default function Second({navigation}) {
  const [loca, setLoca] = useState([]);

  const Get = async () => {
    const myDoc = collection(db, 'users');
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(myDoc);
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
      setLoca({
        id: doc.id,
        fname: doc.data().fname,
      });
      console.log(loca);
    });
  };

  const Logout = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        // Sign-out successful.
        console.log('log out');
        navigation.navigate('Login');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // An error happened.
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Get();
  }, []);

  const renderItemm = ({item}) => <Comp title={item.fname} />;

  return (
    <View style={styles.conn}>
      <ImageBackground source={image} resizeMode="cover" style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 15}}>
          <View style={styles.box}>
            <View style={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
              <Text>HOME</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.box1} onPress={Logout}>
                <Text>dd</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.box1}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Third')}></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          {loca.length > 0 ? (
            <FlatList
              data={loca}
              renderItem={renderItemm}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
          ) : (
            <ActivityIndicator />
          )}
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  conn: {
    //flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1,
  },
  tt: {
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: '#4DA69B',
    fontSize: 24,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    borderRadius: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  box: {
    marginTop: 10,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },

  end: {
    //justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  box1: {
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    borderRadius: 24,
    backgroundColor: '#67BE92',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
  boxxx: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
});
```

comp.js

```
const comp = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.conn}>
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text>{props.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default comp;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  conn: {
    
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  tt: {
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: '#4DA69B',
    fontSize: 24,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    borderRadius: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  box: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: '100%',
    height: 115,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#67BE92',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  end: {
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  box1: {
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    borderRadius: 24,
    backgroundColor: '#67BE92',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
});
```

i dont slove this plobem it show ActivityIndicator not show flatlist I use my firebase data and console.lod(loca) show that data but flatlist not show

solve my flatlist and show in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data passed to the FlatList should always be an array. So you should edit your code as follow:

```
const Get = async () => {
    const myDoc = collection(db, 'users');
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(myDoc);
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
      // I changed the below
      setLoca([...loca, {
        id: doc.id,
        fname: doc.data().fname,
      }]);
      console.log(loca);
    });
  };
```

We are looping over querySnapshot, so this syntax "setLoca([...loca, {..}])" keeps the already saved data while looping.